# File gets created, but subprocess call says no such file or directory

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to redirect the output of a subprocess call to a file

```
def get_arch():
    global ip_vm
    in_cmd = "uname -p"
    with open('/home/thejdeep/arch_list',"w") as outfile:
        print outfile
        subprocess.call(in_cmd,stdout=outfile)
        print "Hello"
    for i in ip_vm:
        cmd = "ssh thejdeep@"+i+" 'uname -p'"
        with open('/home/thejdeep/arch_list',"a") as outpfile:
                subprocess.call(cmd,stdout=outpfile)
```

The file gets created. This I get to know by printing outfile. However, the subprocess call returns a Errno[2] no such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first parameter to `subprocess.call` is incorrect.  It should be a list, not a string.  Compare:

```
>>> subprocess.call('echo hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

With:

```
>>> subprocess.call(['echo', 'hello'])
hello
0
```

If you really want to pass a shell command to `subprocess.call`, you need to set `shell=True`:

```
>>> subprocess.call('echo hello', shell=True)
hello
0
```

You are in general better off using the list version, because this way you don't need to worry about unexpected effects from shell metacharacters in your command strings.